# How to optimize TransactionScope usage in .net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, transactionscope

I am using TransactionScope in my WPF/C# application in order to safeguard financial transactions executing in bulk. However, this is causing locking issue for multiple user scenarios.

When the first user submits bulk transactions from his screen, the second user need to wait until the first one completes his job causing other user's screens to hang for that time.

I thought of setting the isolation level to "read uncommitted", but as I understand, it can result in dirty reads, which is not advised for critical applications like treasury dealing app.

Is there any way to optimize the performance in this scenario (threading, etc.) which can speed up the things for user experience? Also please correct me if wrong - WPF application is a single threaded application, we cannot implement multi threading?

Comment: WPF is definitely multithreaded, the special case is the UI thread. But you start as many as you want.

Comment: Will threading cause the same problem of dirty reads?

Comment: Sure, multithreading does not solve anything on itself. But it can help you in a way that you do the database actions in the background while the endusers ui is not blocked: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx

Comment: If what you need is to keep your UI responsive, you can look into the asynchronous API's offered by ADO.NET and Entity Framework. No need for extra threads at all.